# Unir dataframes por igualdad de dos columnas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo dos dataframes

```
       id    id_producto
       A32      1
       A12      3
       B44      4
```

El segundo

```
      id     id_producto    cantidad
     A09        9             34
     A10        12            10
     A32        1             1
     A32        9             22
     B44        4             3
     B44        22            9
```

Lo que estaria buscado filtrar, seria solo los valores que coincidan las dos columnas id's, en ambos dataframes

```
id        id_producto        cantidad
A32           1                1
B44           4                3
```

No se cómo podria poner una condicion de ese estilo, o si es posible agregandole algo a merge, pero no es la salida que espero dado que no se como considerar a id_producto también

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = {'id': ['A32', 'A12', 'B44'],
  'id_producto': ['1', '3','4'],
  }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1 )

df2 = {'id': ['A09','A10', 'A32', 'A32', 'B44', 'B44'],
         'id_producto': ['9', '12', '1', '9', '4', '22'],
        'cantidad' : [34,10,1,22,3,9]
         }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2 )

pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id' , how='inner')
```

Comment: Simplemente pasa a on una lista con las columnas. on=["id","id_producto"]. Te recomiendo leer la documentacion https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución rápida es sacar las filas del df2 mediante un filtro utilizando la función .isin()

```
df2[df2['id_producto'].isin(df1['id_producto']) ]
```

.isin() se utiliza para filtar los datos presentes en un dataframe y devuelve valores booleanos si la fila en este caso se mira si los id_productos del df2 estan en id_productos del df1.

[Aquí encontrar más información sobre la función](https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/pandas/pandas-isin#:%7E:text=Pandas%20isin%20%28%29%20method%20is%20used%20to%20filter,returned%20DataFrame%20contains%20True%2C%20else%20it%20shows%20False.)

Comment: ¿Por qué utilizar `isin` cuando el `op` ya está utilizando `merge`, que sería la respuesta directa? El problema es que no utiliza el argumento `on` correctamente.

Comment: Esta respuesta no tiene en cuenta filtrar el dataframe tambien por id ni toma columnas del segundo Dataframe. Recomiendo usar merge en su lugar.

Comment: A pesar de que el OP aceptó la respuesta, sigo convencido de que merge esta mejor diseñado para este proposito que isin.

Comment: Concuerdo con sus comentarios, solo mostré una forma que imagino simple y rápida además si resuelve de la forma que el **op** necesita.